# When I type in the all_sessions_raw query, Why do I keep getting an error message saying Syntax Error: Unexpected Keyword TO at [3:11]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to execute the following BigQuery Statement on Google Cloud Platform:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as num_duplicate_rows, * 
FROM
  data-to-insights.ecommerce.all_sessions_raw
GROUP BY
  fullVisitorId, channelGrouping, time, country, city,
  totalTransactionRevenue, transactions, timeOnSite, pageviews,
  sessionQualityDim, date, visitId, type, productRefundAmount,
  productQuantity, productPrice, productRevenue, productSKU,
  v2ProductName, v2ProductCategory, productVariant, currencyCode,
  itemQuantity, itemRevenue, transactionRevenue, transactionId,
  pageTitle, searchKeyword, pagePathLevel1, eCommerceAction_type,
  eCommerceAction_step, eCommerceAction_option
HAVING 
  num_duplicate_rows > 1;
```

I got the following error message:

**Syntax error: Unexpected keyword TO at 3:11**

I am currently trying to use BigQuery on Google Cloud Platform and it fails with the error shown above. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your project `data-to-insights` needs to be enclosed in backticks `\`data-to-insights\``.  Or you could enclose the whole thing... `\`data-to-insights.ecommerce.all_sessions_raw\``.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below query. Works for me.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_duplicate_rows, * 
FROM `data-to-insights.ecommerce.all_sessions_raw` 
GROUP BY fullVisitorId, channelGrouping, time, country, city, totalTransactionRevenue, transactions, timeOnSite, pageviews, sessionQualityDim, date, visitId, type, productRefundAmount, productQuantity, productPrice, productRevenue, productSKU, v2ProductName, v2ProductCategory, productVariant, currencyCode, itemQuantity, itemRevenue, transactionRevenue, transactionId, pageTitle, searchKeyword, pagePathLevel1, eCommerceAction_type, eCommerceAction_step, eCommerceAction_option HAVING num_duplicate_rows > 1
```

The issue is that you have not enclosed project.dataset.table_name in backticks (`).